# What determines the number of columns in Datatables based datatable?

Tags: datatables

I am new to the DataTables plugin,
How does it determine the number of columns to display?
Based on the HTML table? or based on the DataSource?
Or is it some combination of the two ?

Can I have columns in the DataSource that are not rendered as columns?
(but are used for example as a tooltip on another column) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does it determine the number of columns to display?

The answer really depends on how you configure your table (keep reading to see what I mean).

> Based on the HTML table? or based on the DataSource? Or is it some combination of the two ?

If you create a DOM based HTML table with all of your data already in it, then you can see from the [zero configuration example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html) that it will just display all of your columns that are provided.

> Can I have columns in the DataSource that are not rendered as columns? (but are used for example as a tooltip on another column) ?

You can further configure the table to hide certain columns using the `bVisible` parameter in the `aoColumnDefs` or `aoColumns` settings for the table configuration.  See [this example for how to hide columns](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html).

You can then use `mrender` to render a column in a particular way.

Say your data had two columns, ID and Name and you wanted to have Name be displayed but only show the ID as a tooltip when the user mouses over the Name cell.  In your `aoColumns` object, set `bVisible` to false for the ID column and set `mrender` for the Name column as follows:

```
"mrender": function(data, type, full) {
    return '<span title="' + full.ID + '">' + data + '</span>';
}
```

Note that if you're using a data source other than the data embedded in the DOM at load (such as AJAX) you're going to probably want to also specify the `mdata` parameter for each `aoColumns` definition, [as can be seen in this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html).

Best of luck!

Comment: sorry to have taken so long to respond. How does this apply to server side proccessing?  and would it be true to say that the number of columns in the table will be that of the column in the initial (only headers) dom table? (although some of them might be hidden) so that basically the columns in the returned data source should have at least the same number of columns as in the html table unless `aoColumnsDefs`/`aoColumns` with `mdata` and/or `mrender` are used to override the default behaviour?

Comment: @epeleg I think that's more or less accurate.  I don't use full server-side processing in anything I use, but I do retrieve the data via AJAX (server-side processing is a little more intensive in that you're server becomes responsible not only for providing the data but also for some of the lifting that datatables provides, like filtering, sorting, etc.  So before you assume you want serverside - make sure that's really what you want).  In the data that you provide to datatables, you are correct in saying that you need at least the same number of columns -- or else an error will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure I want server side because some of the tables I deal with have thousands of rows.